# Obtaining the user's username via Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to obtain the user's username aka http://foursquare.com/USERNAME via the API.  There seems to be no support for it in the User JSON response nor can I seem to find it anywhere else in the docu. Shouldn't it be available via a User request???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foursquare identifies users by their user ID which is a number. Their default profile location is http://foursquare.com/user/USER_ID. You can also access a user's profile via http://foursquare.com/TWITTER_USERNAME if the user has connected their Twitter handle.

So given a user who has connected their twitter handle "FOOBAR" to foursquare, you can access their profile at http://foursquare.com/FOOBAR.

Comment: so the username isn't discrete to foursquare? it's only if you auth to twitter too? that's interesting. thanks!

Comment: Woah, this is really a crazy way to handle it. Thanks for this answer, I know it's years later, but seeing this strange distinction explained actually helped a lot with something I'm working on now, and it is still accurate.